# Post belongs to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a post model that I want to belong to user. When I did that, I couldn't reference any user things in the view. I'm using Devise.

The post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :album, :artist, :song
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :album, :artist, :song
end
```

The User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :posts

  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  validates_presence_of :username, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

And I tried to reference the username with `<%= post.user.username %>`. I also tried `<%= post.user%>` and `<%= post.user.name %>`.

**UPDATE**: I added `user_id` to the table. However, when I make a post, the `username` and `user_id` values don't get set.

Comment: How about showing your models and how you're trying to reference "user things" so we know what you're talking about?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to make those references?

Comment: are you sure you have an attribute named `user_id` in your `posts` table ?

Comment: @Khaled I forgot that, but when I added it, I'm still having issues. I'm editing it with more info now.

Comment: How bout showing us your controller code? How are you creating a post? Post.new(params[:post]) or current_user.post.new(params[:post])?

Comment: @rainkinz `Post.new(params[:post])`, so that's probably the problem. The thing is, switching it to `current_user.post.new(params[:post])` says that `post` is undefined.

Comment: Because a user has many posts, try with `current_user.posts.new(params[:post])`

Comment: Sorry that should have been current_user.posts.new(params[:post]) as seikfried pointed out. Sorry bout the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I fixed it. [here's my create action](http://pastie.org/5589383). I plan to refactor it to use the Factory pattern.

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.username = current_user.username
@post.user_id = current_user.id
if @post.save
  redirect_to action: "index"
  @posts = Post.find(:all)
else
  render action: 'new'
end
```

Comment: look at building throigh the association.  If user has many posts.  You can do. current_user.posts.create , etc and not have to manually set the user_id